# How to use a public Azure feed

Tags: azure-devops, nuget

Azure documentation says that in a public project you can create a public feed. I did so and also scoped the feed to the organisation rather than project scoped, so that CICD for private projects can push packages to it.

[image: Creating a public feed]

However, selecting the feed and clicking on the "Connect to feed" button, then clicking the dotnet options, produces this.

[image: Connect to feed (dotnet)]

Adding that `nuget.config` to a project then attempting to add a package from the feed fails. If we take the URL from the nuget.config and request it using a browser we get a `401 Forbidden`.

### Why?

Why is authentication required? It's supposed to be a *public* feed. Does public mean "any AAD identity, not just the ones for this organisation" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can also reproduce your issue on my side, the cause of the issue is that you selected the `Scope` with `Organization` when you creating the feed.

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/feeds?view=azure-devops#project-scoped-vs-organization-scoped-feeds):

> Only project-scoped feeds can be made public.

To fix the issue, just select the `Scope` with `Project` when creating the feed, it will work fine.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, in order to have public artefacts with private source I would have to do CICD in a public project with a project scoped public feed?

Comment: If this is by design then the Azure Devops people might want to either disallow change to org scope or update to mention that the feed won't be public when org scope is selected.